# Location : in a text field causing the code to break

Tags: php, laravel, server, request, location

Laravel 5.2
php 7.1

I have a form that contains several field includeing which one is a text field called description. This is very long text field some lines of which are,

WEBSITE:
————————
www.confidential.com
————————

Location:
————————
a short url
————————

This website was previously hosted on an aws machine and was working perfectly fine there.

But then for some reasons it was shifted to namecheap and this problem start appearing.

When I update a car (or create a new car) with **Location:** in description the code crash and laravel throws method not found exception. If I remove : after location, the code succeeds.
Method is put and is specified. Route is defined. AS I mentioned it was working perfectly fine on aws machine.

Edited:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTbTc.png)

Please help.....

Comment: insufficient data , provide more information  (show your error pic)

Comment: @GauravGupta edited

Comment: it say your request type is different . check your route and see what's type it is , for form i think your using post type and route is of get type (not confirm ) . check and share

Comment: @GauravGupta I think you did not understand the question carefully. Let me rephrase it, each car has a field description of type text. When I use these specific words "Location: short url to google map" in description the code breaks. when I remove it, it works perfectly fine. This was was working perfectly fine on aws. The problem is that there are alike 500 cars with same kind of description and now they are not being edited.